# Best Way to Switch Between Basic and Advanced App Settings

Tags: interaction-design, ios, toggle, settings

In my iOS app, I intend to have two types of settings - Basic and Advanced. The Basic settings essentially summarize the more granular 10-11 advanced settings into 3-4 different themes, so most users can simply choose a theme and not bother to modify anything more granular. But advanced users should have the capability to not work with themes and instead be able to change those 10-11 granular setting controls individually.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? So far, I've been thinking of having a standard switch control for Advanced settings - in its 'off' state, only the Basic 3-4 settings would be visible whilst in its 'on' state, the Basic settings would disappear and the granular Advanced controls would kick in for the user to modify.

Does this ring any alarm bells, or have folks implemented such a feature differently before?

So far, I've only seen the sudden appearance of setting controls when a Switch is turned on, but never the disappearance of some controls and appearance of others.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My thought is, try implementing a way to have a swipe from the right to the left of the screen go from Basic to Advanced. It lets more advanced users know it's there without having them go into the Settings app, toggle a switch, quit out of your app, and relaunch to see the Advanced control set.

Do it similar to how SnapChat's "chat" system works; in order to send a message to someone in your list of recents, you swipe from the arrow from left to right.

Put an arrow or an ellipsis (…) somewhere, to let a user know *there's more to be seen.* if they tap, do a bounce effect like the lock screen camera does, to let them know that they have to swipe.

Comment: Much appreciated @DDPWNAGE

Answer (score 0):

Many apps use a second screen for advanced options,  usually accessed by pressing a button at the bottom of a screen with basic settings. At least, that is the most popular option on android and windows. I'm not sure if apple has a different standard, but from what I've seen during short uses of iphones and ipads, it's mostly the same.

It might be a good idea to have the option to base your advanced  theme on one of the  basic themes before setting these options.